# Customizing a form in SharePoint Designer 2010 - Missing list columns in Data Source

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, data-view-web-part, list-form

I've been attempting to create a custom layout for an otherwise standard edit form in SPD 2010.  All behavior with my list and the default new/display/edit forms works correctly.

Per the instructions from the Microsoft support site, i'm planning to hide the existing WebPart that displays the default Edit fields, and I've inserted a Data Form Web Part to house the new layout and edit fields.

Upon doing this, linking it to my source list, I'm seeing the following strange behavior:

- All but one column of type "People or Group" appears in the Data Source window.  There's nothing unique about this column, and it's identical to nine others in the same list that are all behaving as expected in SPD.  I've tried creating new columns using different names, and all of the new columns also fail to appear.  I've searched but can't seem to find anything indicating a bug that might cause this.

The field appears and functions correctly in the default forms, and the only way I've been able to access it on my customized form is by copying the code that points to the form item.  While this might be a workaround solution, I've encountered other challenges when manipulating the default form content and would prefer to avoid that route.

Is there any way to further troubleshoot this?  Is there a limit on the number of 'People or Group' fields that SPD will allow for? I have exactly 10 in my list, but it seems that only 9 will be represented in the Data Form Web Part.

Very frustrated.  Hours lost, between trying to figure this out, and dealing with corrupted form code when attempting to manipulate the working form as an alternate solution.

Thanks!